# Why to calculate chromatic number before coloring the graph?

Tags: coloring

This may be a noob's question, but I really want to know.

What is the necessity to find the chromatic number of a graph before actually coloring it?

**

> Why not just color the graph and find the chromatic number???

**

Thanks for giving time to read my question.

Comment: Because colouring a graph optimally is not always easy, and it may help if you are (somehow) able to determine the correct answer before starting.

Comment: Thanks @David for a quick reply. Is coloring will be easier after knowing the chromatic number of a graph? What if my graph is small and easier to color?

Comment: If it's small enough that you can be **sure** (say, with a small amount of trial and error) that you have used the minimum number of colours, then there is probably no need to calculate the chromatic number by any other method.

Comment: Thanks hopefully I got the answer. Thanks for your time @David

Answer (score 1):

If we want to find a $\chi(G)$-coloring of $G$, then we have to know what $\chi(G)$ is.

Knowing what $\chi(G)$ is can be used to reduce the search space for a $\chi(G)$-coloring (we don't need to search among $k$-colorings with $k \neq \chi(G)$).

In the other direction, having a $k$-coloring of $G$ does not help prove that there are no $(k-1)$-colorings of $G$.